# Intellisense in Visual Studio 2013 isn't working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide, intellisense

I was writing code, when suddenly Intellisense stopped working. 
I've had this problem in the past and fixed it by restarting Visual Studio.

I'm trying get Intellisense to work without restarting.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using any extensions? That's a common issue that I ran into. One of my extensions (ReSharper or Visual Assist X) would overwrite several of the settings, and I had to go into the settings for that extension to enable intelisense again.

Also, which language is this for?

Comment: yes,i sure don't use any extensions, in C# language

Comment: In that case, I'm not quite sure. This was the most common issue for me. 

Your best bet at this point may be to uninstall then reinstall VS.